# How to connect QGIS (linux) to SQL Server

Tags: qgis, sql-server, odbc

I tried every thing I can think of, official Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server, FreeTDS, etc.... I'm able to connect to the SQL Server DB from the terminal (isql,sqsh) I can use PostgreSQL's Foreign Data Wrapper to connect PG and MSSQL, but I can't connect QGIS. I get the same error:

```
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
```

How do I connect linux QGIS to SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can find an answer in [this giude](http://getspatial.com/gisblog/qgis-vector-data-connection). Look up for "Add MySQL Spatial Layer"

Comment: I had tried It, also no success. What I noticed is that QGIS removes MS ODBC `The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libodbc1-utf16 msodbcsql odbcinst-utf16 odbcinst1debian2-utf16
  unixodbc-dev-utf16 unixodbc-utf16
`. Is it a bug?